# PHP print_r private object

Tags: php, object

I have an object that has private keys like this `_errors:private`. I am trying to `print_r` farther down the multidimensional array (to get specific error codes). But when i try the `print_r` comes up empty. How do I get thous objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is private it means that it cannot be accesed from outside the class. You could writte a "getter", wich is a function that will return that value. You can think that as a bank vault and a teller. You cannot get your money from the vault yourself, you have to ask the teller (in programming, the getter) to go to te vault and get if to you.

```
private $secret_var;

public function secret_var_getter(){
   return $secret_var;
}
```

in this example, trying to do `$object->secret_var` will throw and error as it is a private property, but calling `$object->secret_var_getter();` will get you the private var.

Answer (score 0):

Make 'em public, write a getter, or use [`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php).